# Remove space after comma in String regex java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a string which contain comma separated data:

```
1,  What is your name ?,  Male,  Cell no
2,  From which country you belong,  USA,  Greetings
```

I'm using this regex but it doesn't do the job:

```
 str.replace(/\s/g, "")
```

Hwo can I convert the String to:

```
1,What is your name ?,Male,Cell no
2,From which country you belong,USA,Greetings
```

Comment: `str.replace( ",\\s+", "," )`

Comment: Looks like CSV. Why not read the CSV in with a CSV parser and strip all of the cells? A regex solution won't work if some cells have quoted data with spaces that aren't padding around delimiters.

Comment: Still the space is present

Comment: `split ("\\s*,\\s*")` should do it for you

Comment: Yes exactly I'm writing this data to csv but each cell contain spaces. How can I strip the cells ?

Comment: @g00se split is for array it doesn't work for string. Syntax error

Comment: `spit` is a method of `String`. You said you have `String`s

Comment: Oops, I think you're right about that, @user16320675  That's what I get for not checking the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68303938/remove-space-after-comma-in-string-regex-java/68304222#comment120717353_68303938), you want to trim the values before writing them to CSV. This can be done by setting the [`withTrim`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withTrim--)-option on the `CSVFormat`:

```java
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withTrim();

try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt", false);
     CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, csvFormat)) {
    csvPrinter.printRecord("1", "  What is your name ?", "  Male", "  Cell no");
    csvPrinter.printRecord("2", "  From which country you belong", "  USA", "  Greetings");
}
```

Content of `file.txt` after execution:

```
1,What is your name ?,Male,Cell no
2,From which country you belong,USA,Greetings
```